# Google Play SSL security alert from GameMaker app with Playscape SDK

Tags: android, ssl, google-play, game-maker, playscape

I got the following error message after uploading an app to Google Play:
[We wanted to know that your application is statically linked against a version of OpenSSL that has multiple security vulnerabilities for users. (...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGc9Y.png)

The error also included the following command: $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL". I executed this command and got the following output:

```
GmsCore_OpenSSL
OpenSSLDie
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-512 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Stack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSLDie
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-512 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Stack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSLDie
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-512 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Stack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
OpenSSLDie
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
lhash part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
SHA-512 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
DlStack part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RSA part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
Big Number part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
RAND part of OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
```

This makes me think there's a problem somewhere with Google Play Services, as the first line is "GmsCore_OpenSSL". However, I'm not sure about this. I looked at the OpenSSL FAQ as the error messages say, but found nothing that was of use.

The app is made using GameMaker: Studio. As I can't find anything about this error in relation to GameMaker: Studio, I think it's not directly the fault of that program, though. The app is also using the Playscape SDK, and I think this SDK might be part of the problem (but I'm, again, not sure). Next to this, the program doesn't use any special SDK's.

I did some research and found [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-and-openssl-warning-message). However, the script on the accepted answer didn't work. I also found [OpenSSL App rejection issue Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536314/openssl-app-rejection-issue-android), which seems to be about the same error as mine, but that question has no answer.

What could be the cause of this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Florian, Can you connect us directly? sharonh@playscape.com

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved with a newer playscape SDK Version 1.15